# How to get data from Web API service - Unable to load a drop down list with api response via knockout JS

Tags: javascript, c#, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I am working on a Web API application which has a drop down list that should be populated with API response which is in xml using knockout JS. I was trying using the following

```
$.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: '/api/UserProfiles',
         data: JSON.stringify(self.brokerNames),
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            self.brokerNames((ko.utils.arrayMap(data.value, function (broker) {
                var obsBrokers = {
                    UserId: broker.UserId,
                    UserName: broker.UserName
                }

                return obsBrokers;
            })));
        }
    });
```

I tried binding above response to a drop down as follows

```
<td>
  <select id="cbxBCP" data-bind="options: brokerNames, 
      optionsText: 'UserName', optionsValue: 'UserName', 
      value: selectedBidBroker, optionsCaption: 'Bid Broker'">
  </select>
</td>
```

But, the above returned an empty drop down. I'm not sure what the issue is but I saw the XML response when debugging with Postman.

The Web API is this

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
public IEnumerable<UserProfile> Get()
{
    return db.UserProfiles.OrderBy(c => c.UserName);
}
```

and seems to work fine.

May I know how I can fix this?

Comment: `data` is your returned XML, so `data.value` would be undefined.  I don't see any attempt to parse the XML at all; this code appears to be written for a JSON response.

Comment: I'm pretty much new to consuming an api, may I know how I can do that

Comment: What's inside your web api action? What does it return? Have you debugged your js (you can press F12 in your browser to see the console)? Shouldn't you be using `data`instead of `data.value`? You don't make clear what verb is usign your action, and if it's expecting parameters: why do you add data to your $.ajax()? read the dcs and see samples for $.get

Comment: @JotaBe My web api action returns all users in xml format and I did debug my js and I dont see any exceptions in the console and my action is a `httpget` and I still get xml response and I'm not sure how to parse it to json and pu it in dropdown.. edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web API returns XML format by default, or the format specified in the accepts header.

In your invocation of `$.ajax` you're not specifying a format, so you get XML. To get JSON you need to provide one of these two [$.ajax options](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

- accepts, use `accepts='application/json'`
- datatype, use `dataType='json'`

If you read the docs you'll see that the second option, besides, parses the received JSON, so that your data parameter is directly a JavaScript object.

*NOTE: you don't need to register the JSON formatter in the Web API as it's available by default*

*NOTE 2: for correctly debugging Web API you need to use a tool like [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) chrome extension, which allows you to specify header (the accepts header explained above), and send and receive JSON data easyly, using any verb GET, POST, PUT, DELETE... If you simply type a URL in yout browser you only get the default format (XML), and you can only test GET actions, which is really unhelpful*